# фильтр по подразделам раздела

Tags: битрикс

В битриксе предусмотрено создание фильтра по свойствам, можно ли сделать умный фильтр по подразделам раздела?

Comment: Штатными средствами только с помощью свойства типа "Привязка к разделу", но никто не мешает создать свой фильтр или допилить умный до нужного состояния.

Comment: @НиколайСарры, с помощью result-modier.php или создать свой компонент?

Comment: можно создать свой компонент, можно через result_modifier.php. Но я бы делал в инфоблоке свойство с типом "Привязка к разделу" или поставить из Маркетплэйс решение Антона Долганина "Инфоблоки, инструменты" и создавал свойство с типом "Привязка к собственной секции". Ну и выводил св-во в фильтр. Не стоит раньше времени пилить компонент.

Comment: @НиколайСарры, спасибо. я добавила свойство Раздел с типом "Привязка к разделу" именно собственного инфоблока (я не стала выбирать инфоблок, так как здесь не указан собственный инфоблок), я так понимаю, это свойство нужно заполнять Ид раздела.Просто автоматом не проявляется.

Comment: для автомата можно написать обработку в `init.php`, но нужно подумать на какое событие вешать. Тип "Привязка к собственной секции" появляющийся после установки решения для инфоблоков Антона Долганина как раз таки автоматическое.

Comment: https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/the-correct-filter-bitrixcatalogsection-filter-sections/